# Can a for loop be written to create an infinite loop or is it only while loops that do that?

Tags: java, for-loop

Can a for loop be written in Java to create an infinite loop or is it only while loops that cause that problem?

Comment: I'm new to programming - my textbook mentions infinite loops only in the context of a while-loop.

Comment: A for loop is only another syntax for a while loop. Everything which is possible with one of them is also possible with the other one.

Comment: Any for loop where the termination condition can never be met will be infinite: `for($i = 0; $i > -1; $i++) { ... }`

Answer (score 17):

```
for(;;){}
```

is same as

```
while(true){}
```

Comment: This is quite the nitpick (and may in fact be incorrect, anyway--I got it from a kid two grades above me in high school), but I'd heard that `for(;;)` gets compiled into a non-conditional `jmp` or whatever, while for `while(true)` it first checks that `true` evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 10):

You can also do such with for loops. E.g. the following is identical to `while(true)`:

```
for(;;) {
}
```

Comment: Use `for(;;);` for a shorter endless loop :-)

Answer (score 9):

Apart from issues of scope and one other thing, this:

```
for(<init>; <test>; <step>) {
  <body>
}
```

is the same as:

```
<init>
while(<test>) {
  <body>
  <step>
}
```

As other people have alluded to, in the same way that you can have a `while` loop without an `<init>` form or `<step>` form, you can have a `for` loop without them:

```
while(<test>) {
  <body>
}
```

is the same as

```
for(;<test>;) {
  <body>
} //Although this is terrible style
```

And finally, you could have a

```
for(;true;) {
  <body>
}
```

Now, remember when I said there was one other thing? It's that `for` loops don't *need* a test--yielding the solution everyone else has posted:

```
for(;;) {
  <body>
}
```

Comment: You forgot the for-each loop — you could always write an iterator that loops forever >:-D

Answer (score 6):

Sure you can

```
for(int i = 0; i == i; i++) {}
```

Any loop can be made infinite as long as you make a way to never hit the exit conditions.

Answer (score 4):

Dont forget mistakes like

```
for (int i=0; i<30; i++)
{
    //code
   i--;
}
```

It's not as uncommon as it should be.

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun (and this too long for a comment): a **lot** of people will be very surprised to learn that for a lot of very practical purposes the following is *nearly* an infinite loop:

```
    for (long i = Long.MIN_VALUE; i < Long.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
        ...
    }
```

If the thread executing this loops can do 4 billions cycles per second and can do the increment and the check in one cycle (quite beefy for a single thread) and if my maths ain't totally off, I think the above code needs about 150 years to execute : )

Answer (score 2):

I'll just add this since nobody did this version:

```
for(;;);
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I made my server to run as long until I shut it down is

`for(int i = 0;i<-1;i++){//code here}`

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse for loops can cause infinite loops. An example is:

for(int i = 0; i < 99; i /= 2){
...
}

Because `i` is never incremented, it will stay in the body of the `for` loop forever until you quit the program.

Answer (score 0):

There is also this one, to complete the topic:

```
do {something();} while(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of ways to make for loops infinite.  This is the solution I found:

```
int j = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
  //insert code here
  j++;
}
```

This works really well for me because it allows the loop to check an infinite amount of values as well as looping infinitely.

Answer (score -1):

you can declare a subpart of the code to be another part in a for loop, example -

```
public class (classname) {
    for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; i <= 4; j++) {
    system.out.println(i + "*" + j + "=" (i*j));
}
```

}

it is almost in infinite loop; if you change int to long, and add more variables, you can practically make it last 25 x 10^12 minutes long

Comment: Lasting longer doesn't make it an infinite loop!