# Why are while and do-while loops preferred over for loops when looping infinitely?

Tags: java, loops, infinite-loop

I'm new to programming and am in my first year of computer science and am a bit confused about loops. When it comes to infinite loops, why are while and do-while loops preferred over for loops? I created a simple infinite for loop and it's just as easy as creating a while loop. Is one type of loop faster than the other?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347862/can-a-for-loop-be-written-to-create-an-infinite-loop-or-is-it-only-while-loops-t

Comment: BTW, speaking of speed when dealing with infinite loops sounds... weird. )

Answer (score 6):

Because it's easier to write (AND read the intention of) `while(true)` than `for(;;)`, perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

A "for()" loop is pretty much equivalent to initializing an index, declaring a while() condition, and incrementing/decrementing the loop.

There is absolutely *no* performance difference.

"while (true)" is generally preferred over "for (;;)" except for people like me who've read and revere the original K & R "White Book" - "The C Programming Language" :)

Answer (score 2):

Neither one is faster than the other. It's just that:

```
while (true)
{
}
```

looks more intuitive and human-readable than:

```
for (; ; )
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`while(true)` is simpler to read than `for(;;)` - you don't need to figure out what it means - it's almost spelled out in English.